# Pyqt: Execute Command

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, pyqt

I am trying to execute command lines in a pyqt application, here is what I am doing so far:

```
stdouterr = os.popen4(cmd)[1].read()
```

simple, and for the most part it does work, but when I open up a text file for example, the pyqt programs stops until the text file is closed. Is there a way I can have something like that open and not stop my application.

Edit:

Okay I almost figured it out. I am currently doing this:

```
Popen(cmd, shell=True,
         stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

which does want I want it to, but is there a way to read stdout and stderr after the process is done running?

Comment: the `os.popen` family of functions is [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.popen). Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
#my pyqt knowledge is not the best but this works for me... didn't use your example. hope you get it still.
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

process = QProcess()
process.start("yourcommand")
process.waitForStarted()
process.waitForFinished()
process.readAll()
process.close()

'''
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
process = QProcess()
process.start('driverquery')
process.waitForStarted()
process.waitForFinished():
process.waitForReadyRead()
tasklist = process.readAll()
process.close()
tasklist = str(tasklist).strip().split("\\r\\n")
print(tasklist)
'''
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from `stdout` and `stderr` like so:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```